# Можно ли создать glow эффект в SVG?

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg

Я изучаю SVG, и я хотел бы знать, возможно ли создать такой эффект свечения с SVG, в интерактивном режиме, как в следующем примере- наведение вызывает эффект -  [пример](https://codepen.io/FelixRilling/pen/qzfoc)

Дело в том, что мне интересно, как заставить свет загораться и затухать, преимущество SVG было бы более точным эффектом с лучшей формой следования, и такого рода преимуществом. Возможно ли это сделать с помощью SVG?

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #2b2b2b 0%, #2b2b2b 10%, #222222 0%, #222222 50%) 0 / 15px 15px;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

/*Neon*/
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7em;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

p:nth-child(1) a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Monoton;
  -webkit-animation: neon1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(1) a:hover {
  color: #FF1177;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  animation: none;
}

p:nth-child(2) a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #228DFF;
  font-family: Iceland;
}

p:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(3) a {
  color: #FFDD1B;
  font-family: Pacifico;
}

p:nth-child(3) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon3 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon3 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon3 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(4) a {
  color: #B6FF00;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

p:nth-child(4) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon4 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon4 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon4 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(5) a {
  color: #FF9900;
  font-family: Audiowide;
}

p:nth-child(5) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon5 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon5 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon5 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p:nth-child(6) a {
  color: #BA01FF;
  font-family: Vampiro One;
}

p:nth-child(6) a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon6 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon6 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon6 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

p a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
/*glow for webkit*/

@-webkit-keyframes neon1 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 70px #FF1177, 0 0 80px #FF1177, 0 0 100px #FF1177, 0 0 150px #FF1177;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF1177, 0 0 35px #FF1177, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 50px #FF1177, 0 0 75px #FF1177;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon2 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 70px #228DFF, 0 0 80px #228DFF, 0 0 100px #228DFF, 0 0 150px #228DFF;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #228DFF, 0 0 35px #228DFF, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon3 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon4 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 70px #B6FF00, 0 0 80px #B6FF00, 0 0 100px #B6FF00, 0 0 150px #B6FF00;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #B6FF00, 0 0 35px #B6FF00, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 50px #B6FF00, 0 0 75px #B6FF00;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon5 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 70px #FF9900, 0 0 80px #FF9900, 0 0 100px #FF9900, 0 0 150px #FF9900;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF9900, 0 0 35px #FF9900, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 50px #FF9900, 0 0 75px #FF9900;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon6 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de, 0 0 150px #ff00de;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #ff00de, 0 0 35px #ff00de, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 50px #ff00de, 0 0 75px #ff00de;
  }
}
/*glow for mozilla*/

@-moz-keyframes neon1 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 70px #FF1177, 0 0 80px #FF1177, 0 0 100px #FF1177, 0 0 150px #FF1177;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF1177, 0 0 35px #FF1177, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 50px #FF1177, 0 0 75px #FF1177;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon2 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 70px #228DFF, 0 0 80px #228DFF, 0 0 100px #228DFF, 0 0 150px #228DFF;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #228DFF, 0 0 35px #228DFF, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon3 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon4 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 70px #B6FF00, 0 0 80px #B6FF00, 0 0 100px #B6FF00, 0 0 150px #B6FF00;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #B6FF00, 0 0 35px #B6FF00, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 50px #B6FF00, 0 0 75px #B6FF00;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon5 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 70px #FF9900, 0 0 80px #FF9900, 0 0 100px #FF9900, 0 0 150px #FF9900;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF9900, 0 0 35px #FF9900, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 50px #FF9900, 0 0 75px #FF9900;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes neon6 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de, 0 0 150px #ff00de;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #ff00de, 0 0 35px #ff00de, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 50px #ff00de, 0 0 75px #ff00de;
  }
}
/*glow*/

@keyframes neon1 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 70px #FF1177, 0 0 80px #FF1177, 0 0 100px #FF1177, 0 0 150px #FF1177;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF1177, 0 0 35px #FF1177, 0 0 40px #FF1177, 0 0 50px #FF1177, 0 0 75px #FF1177;
  }
}

@keyframes neon2 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 70px #228DFF, 0 0 80px #228DFF, 0 0 100px #228DFF, 0 0 150px #228DFF;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #228DFF, 0 0 35px #228DFF, 0 0 40px #228DFF, 0 0 50px #228DFF, 0 0 75px #228DFF;
  }
}

@keyframes neon3 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}

@keyframes neon4 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 70px #B6FF00, 0 0 80px #B6FF00, 0 0 100px #B6FF00, 0 0 150px #B6FF00;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #B6FF00, 0 0 35px #B6FF00, 0 0 40px #B6FF00, 0 0 50px #B6FF00, 0 0 75px #B6FF00;
  }
}

@keyframes neon5 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 70px #FF9900, 0 0 80px #FF9900, 0 0 100px #FF9900, 0 0 150px #FF9900;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FF9900, 0 0 35px #FF9900, 0 0 40px #FF9900, 0 0 50px #FF9900, 0 0 75px #FF9900;
  }
}

@keyframes neon6 {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de, 0 0 150px #ff00de;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #ff00de, 0 0 35px #ff00de, 0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 50px #ff00de, 0 0 75px #ff00de;
  }
}
/*REEEEEEEEEEESPONSIVE*/

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red">
        RED
    </a></p>

    <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue">
        BLUE
    </a></p>

    <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow">
        Yellow
    </a></p>

    <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green">
        GREEN
    </a></p>

    <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(colour)">
        ORANGE
    </a></p>

    <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violet_(color)">
        VIOLET
    </a></p>

</div>

<div id="linkBack" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;background-color:#333;margin:0;width:60px;padding:5px"><a href="http://www.f-rilling.com/projects/" target="_blank" style="font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;padding:0 0 0 5px;font-family:sans-serif">My Site</a></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Is it possible to create a glow effect in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54112231/7394871) от участника  [@HoCo_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9638302/hoco).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54112231/7394871

Comment: Саша скажите плиз...есть ли в svg что то типа border-radius только для stroke ?

Comment: не совсем то - вот [смотри тут](https://codepen.io/lukemeyrick/pen/qdxqwM) каким образом закруглить треугольник ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88434/discussion-between---and-alexandr-tt).

Answer (score 7):

Вот базовая настройка:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300">
  <filter id="neon">
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(255,255,128)" flood-opacity="0.5" in="SourceGraphic" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
    <feComponentTransfer result="glow1">
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="4" intercept="0" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feMerge>
       <feMergeNode in="glow1" />
       <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="100" font-family="sans-serif" x="50%" y="200" fill="yellow" filter="url(#neon)">NEON</text>
</svg>
```

- 'Flood-Color' - это цвет свечения.
- `stdDeviation` - приблизительный размер, более высокие значения
  означают меньшую интенсивность
- `slope` усиливает свечение и противодействует разбавлению размытия по
  Гауссу. flood-opacity` делает то же самое, но имеет верхний предел 1
- если вы хотите получить свечение перед буквами, измените порядок с
  `<feMergeNode>`s
- если вы хотите наложить несколько слоев свечения, как в примере на
  `codepen`, повторите примитивы фильтра, кроме последнего `<feMerge>`,
  и добавьте их результат в том порядке, в котором вы хотите, чтобы они
  `<feMerge>`

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115866/7394871):[@ccprog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996779/ccprog)

Answer (score 7):

Да, это возможно.

Основная идея состоит в том, чтобы использовать фильтр, чтобы размыть форму, закрасить размытую форму неоновым цветом, а затем поместить его за исходный текст.

Однако, чтобы добиться лучшего неонового свечения, вам нужно повозиться с цветами и интенсивностью свечения. В следующем примере я использовал серию пятен разного количества, сложенных вместе, чтобы добиться лучшего эффекта.
Это похожий подход к кодовому блоку, с которым вы связаны. Но будут и другие способы сделать это.

Обратите внимание, что для простоты конкретное определение фильтра, использованное здесь, предполагает, что исходная форма (текст) будет белой. Это может не работать с другими цветами. Но фильтр можно настроить, чтобы обойти эту проблему.

```css
svg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 400px;
}

text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sansserif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: white;
  filter: url(#red-glow);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <filter id="red-glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
       <!-- blur the text at different levels-->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur5"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur10"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" result="blur20"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="30" result="blur30"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50" result="blur50"/>
      <!-- merge all the blurs except for the first one -->
      <feMerge result="blur-merged">
        <feMergeNode in="blur10"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur20"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur30"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur50"/>
      </feMerge>
      <!-- recolour the merged blurs red-->
      <feColorMatrix result="red-blur" in="blur-merged" type="matrix"
                     values="1 0 0 0 0
                             0 0.06 0 0 0
                             0 0 0.44 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="red-blur"/>       <!-- largest blurs coloured red -->
        <feMergeNode in="blur5"/>          <!-- smallest blur left white -->
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  <!-- original white text -->
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <text x="200" y="200" text-anchor="middle">RED</text>
</svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115910/7394871):@[Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau)