# Как сделать текст как на диодном табло?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, css-animation

Как сделать анимированный текст, чтоб выглядел как на диодном табло на черном фоне?

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/933494/262779

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда-то мне попадался пример реализации данной задачи, упрощю вам поиск.
Урезанный вариант кода, под поставленную задачу:

```js
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('input').keyup(function(){ jQuery(this).next().find('.line_text').html(this.value)}).keyup();
})
```

```css
.container{
    width:500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  input{
    test-align:center;
    width:500px;
    height:24px;
    font-size:17px;
    margin-top:50px;
    text-align:center;
  }

  .line {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid #dddddd;
    box-shadow:0px 5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-radius:2px;
    position:relative;
  }

  .line .line_cover{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background:url(https://html5.by/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/led_bg.png);
  }

  .line .line_text{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
  }

  #l1.line{
    height:70px;
    background:rgb(50,80,50);
  }

  #l1.line .line_text{
    font-size:60px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#00ff00;
    -webkit-animation: l1_animation 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: l1_animation 10s linear infinite;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes l1_animation {
      0%{left:100%;}
      100%{left:-100%;}
  }
  @-moz-keyframes l1_animation {
      0%{left:100%;}
      100%{left:-100%;}
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input placeholder = "type here" value="H T M L 5 B Y">
  <div class="line" id="l1">
    <div class="line_text"></div>
    <div class="line_cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://html5.by/blog/html5-led-panel-with-electronic-moving-text/)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Arcadiy Если будет интересно поигратся с отдельными диодами, то глянь тут: https://codepen.io/fskirschbaum/pen/MYJNaj

Comment: Круто, спасибо!

Comment: @L.F.C. Симпотично смотрится!  Вспомнил аналогичную работу [бегущей строки в стиле - "Школы старых мастеров"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/765520/28748),  когда не было цветных дисплеев